# how to remember the last page you read in android pdfviewer

Tags: android, pdf, save, viewer

I made an Android app to read PDF from assets folder
but the problem is when I close app when and re-open it the next time It open from page 1.
I want it to remember the last page read
How can I do this.
This is my `MainActivity` code:

```
package com.geso.ebookoffline;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("book.pdf")
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be similar to [handling this on configuration changes](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#how-can-i-show-last-opened-page-after-configuration-change): "You have to store current page number and then set it with pdfView.defaultPage(page), refer to sample app"

Comment: can you give me the full code and where to put it exactly?

Comment: how can I get the scroll animation when it loads the current page. Suppose my last load page was 10. when I open the pdf its directly showing 10th page. Is there any setting so that it shows the 10th page with scroll animation. Any help is greatly appreciated.